How do I write a function that "converts" an arrow function to a normal function?
For example, can I write some function (call it convert) that can convert an arrow function to a normal function? I want to bind the function to some object but I can't do that for arrow functions. For example:

function test1() { console.log(this.a); }
const test2 = () => { console.log(this.a); }

const obj = { a: 4 };

function foo(f) {
    (f.bind(obj))();
}

foo(test1); //outputs 4 because `this` is `obj`
foo(test2); //outputs undefined because `this` is the window

I would like to write a function convert such that foo(test2) also outputs 4.
I initially tried something like
function convert(f) {
    return function() { f(); }
}

but that didn't seem to work.
EDIT: I've seen the other answers about similar topics and I understand that you can't bind this in an arrow function. My question is different in the sense that I ask if we can convert an arrow function to a normal function in order to be able to bind this (to circumvent that limitation of arrow functions), rather than how to bind this in an arrow function.

Nope! I don't believe this is possible. Would be really interested to see how if so.

dang, that's unfortunate
